# Watson dialogue, movie find demo code: The words on the home page of this bot cannot be changed

Tags: dialog, find, ibm-cloud, movie, watson-conversation

I made the following Watson demo app code work in Bluemix cloud. Went through many files in this demo app. 
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversational-agent

The working bot is here:
https://movieb4testcnvservice.mybluemix.net

Yesterday, I changed the words "Chat with Watson" on the above bot and saved the file as home.html.  But after many reloads, the words "Chat with Watson" are still in the above bot. What caused this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `conversational-agent` was deprecated a few months ago. There is no replacement and it was based on the Dialog service which will be discontinued in August. See: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/dialog.html